# Asp.net: DetailsView cancels update when redirecting

Tags: c#, detailsview

I have a DetailsView control like so:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="IssueId"
    DataSourceID="edsIssues" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted"
    OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated"
    OnItemUpdating="DetailsView1_ItemUpdating">
    <Fields>
```

After inserting and updating I want to redirect to another page (a list page containing a GridView).  So I did this:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("IssueList.aspx");
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("IssueList.aspx");
}
```

When inserting a new record it works fine.  However, when updating a record the Redirect causes the Update to cancel.

If I remove the Repsonse.Redirect from ItemUpdated then the update works - but then the DetailsView loads blank (I guess in insert mode).

How can I redirect to another page after updating without cancelling the update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to set a timer before the redirection process like : System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); Response.Redirect("IssueList.aspx");

Comment: won't that just slow down the site?

Comment: just on the update process you should add this line  on DetailsView1_ItemUpdated event

Comment: Well, it works in so much that the update takes place. However it does slow down the site.  As a test I increased the Sleep amount to 20,000 and it does indeed hold up the whole site. I don't think this is a good solution, it certainly won't scale.

Comment: if you increased the sleep amount to 20 000 it's like saying to your browser to stop working for 20 sec and indeed will slow down your site

Comment: 20,000 was just a test to see if using Sleep would hold it up.  I used an extreme example to prove a point.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that even with 2000 the site will slow down when you scale up to lots of users.

Comment: ItemUpdated is fired when object is updated (not updating), so I don't understant how Redirect can cancel update when it already happened? I think that something else is wrong.

Comment: I agree - but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't like the answer as it seems wrong - using Threading.Thread.Sleep() did in fact do the job.  I would love to know if there was a better answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for VB

Protected Sub dv_Itemclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs) Handles yourDetailsViewitem.ItemCommand
        If (e.CommandName = "Cancel") Then
            Response.Redirect("yourPage.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub